# Delete a row with type cast

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, types

I need to remove a row from a table where is no primary key. Don't blame me, Hibernate creates them. I can't use OID or CTID. Luck that I have the whole row data and I use that.

This works:

```
DELETE FROM public.item WHERE public.item='(4,A015GV,444,s4)'::item;
```

This also works:

```
DELETE FROM public.item WHERE item='(5,A015GH,555,s5)'::public.item;
```

But if schema is mentioned 3 times, it is *not* working. Why?

```
DELETE FROM public.item WHERE public.item='(5,A015GH,555,s5)'::public.item;
```

Comment: It is not schema mentioned 3 times, you aliased column in where but you don't have `public` table alias. Try `DELETE FROM public.item thealias WHERE thealias.item='(5,A015GH,555,s5)'::public.item;`

Comment: @Izzy is the first case really working? "DELETE FROM public.item WHERE public.item='(4,A015GV,444,s4)'::item;"

Comment: I works every now and then. Not allways.

Comment: Fix to JustMe's example
DELETE FROM public.item thealias WHERE thealias='(5,A015GH,555,s5)'::public.item;

Comment: The Postgres query parser doesn't just reject a statement "every now and then". A statement is either syntactically valid, or it isn't. And that first statement is not, at least in 9.5. What version of Postgres are you running?

Answer (score 0):

just add ::text

```
DELETE FROM public.item WHERE item::text='(5,A015GH,555,s5)';
```

Comment: It worked, but why
DELETE FROM public.item WHERE public.item::text='(5,A015GH,555,s5)';
or
DELETE FROM public.item WHERE (public.item)::text='(5,A015GH,555,s5)';
does not ?

Comment: replace  (public.item)::text  by  (item)::text